# How does one use join in mysql and avoid duplicate entries in response

Tags: mysql, sql

i've tried both of these and continue to get a duplicate for each credit data entry:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
FROM  `mediaDATA` 
LEFT JOIN media_creditsDATA ON mediaDATA.id = media_creditsDATA.media_id

SELECT * 
FROM  `mediaDATA` 
LEFT JOIN media_creditsDATA ON mediaDATA.id = media_creditsDATA.media_id
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that on a normalised data set `DISTINCT *` is oxymoronic

Comment: For further help see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you provide some sample data as of how mediaDATA table and media_creditsDATA  looks like?

Comment: What do you mean, "get a duplicate for each credit data entry"? Yes, there are multiple rows with the same mediaDATA.id value because the join pairs it with each matching row in media_creditsDATA when there is one and NULLs otherwise. If that's not what you want, what you do you want? You don't say, you just give two *wrong* queries and *wrong* output with no corresponding DDL or input and an unclear complaint. Please edit your question to be clear. Please read & act on [mcve]. You question should not have been answered & it should be downvoted and closed. Help us help you.

Comment: Only that, in a normalised environment '`*`' effectively negates '`DISTINCT`'

Comment: @philipxy It is not possible to have duplicates occuring across *all* columns.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry to keep interrupting your poetic reverie. Why not just write something clear & helpful? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: There's nothing poetic about "select distinct" being useless when you also select all columns from normalised data. It is also wasteful and a major cause of slowness in queries when abused by those who don't understand that the term "distinct" simply means that each row will be **in some way different to every other row**. If your tables are properly normalised then **by definition** each row is different. So the oxymoron is formed in *"select distinct * from table"* because it is asking *"select rows that are unique and different from a set of rows that are unique and different"*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, use `distinct *` is counterintuitive, you are essentially selecting every row in the table then eliminating duplicate rows. Try to avoid using that.

since you have tried `distinct` it eliminated the possibility where you start off with duplicate data in your tables. 
looking at your screenshot I think the rows are **not duplicate**. They might be **identical on certain columns but can't be completely identical.** for example.

```
media:
id          name
----------- ---------------
1           mediaA
2           mediaB
3           mediaC

media_creditsDATA:
media_id    credit_id  name
----------- ----------- ---------------
1           1           good credit
1           2           ok credit
2           3           bad credit
3           4           no credit
```

if you execute the following sql with `distinct` or not the result is the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM  media
INNER JOIN media_creditsDATA ON media.id = media_creditsDATA.media_id
```

result:

```
id          name            media_id    credit_id  name
----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------
1           mediaA          1           1           good credit
1           mediaA          1           2           ok credit
2           mediaB          2           3           bad credit
3           mediaC          3           4           no credit
```

If you only look at the first three columns in the result table then sure there are duplicate records, but not if you look at all the columns. As you can see the media table has a **one to many** relationship to media_creditsDATA table. **The result table has records that share the same subset of columns but there are no duplicate records.**

---

so I think the problem in this case is not how you join is **how you filter** your result. such as is there a subset of credit records you are looking for in media_creditsDATA table? or maybe you don't care and you just record with highest credit_id for each media records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  media
INNER JOIN (
    select media_id, max(credit_id) as highest_credit_id from media_creditsDATA 
     group by media_id )media_creditsDATA ON media.id = media_creditsDATA.media_id
```

you get:

```
id          name            media_id    highest_credit_id
----------- --------------- ----------- --------------
1           mediaA          1           2
2           mediaB          2           3
3           mediaC          3           4
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want duplicated  row you should use distinct and explicit column name for only the values you really need
eg:

```
  SELECT distinct id, company_id, associated_company_id, title, year,  `desc`, media_file
  FROM  mediaDATA 
  LEFT JOIN media_creditsDATA ON mediaDATA.id = media_creditsDATA.media_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mediaDATA LEFT JOIN media_creditsDATA 
ON mediaDATA.id = media_creditsDATA.media_id
where mediaDATA.id in (
select DISTINCT(media_id)
from media_creditsDATA 
)
```

most people would say that you should add a DISTINCT on the id on the main Select. You can try that, but Im quite sure it will decrese performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicates in your first statement because there are multiple rows in the media_creditsDATA table with the same media_id, as it is not the PK of media_creditsData. The non-key data of this table could be the same across all media_ids (which would be a strange model), but we certainly cannot assume so. Given that, distinct will be unreliable for this purpose.

You have a couple of options:

Select a distinct subset of fields from media_creditsDATA and join to it, like:

```
select * 
from mediaData
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select distinct media_id, field1, field2, field3 from media_creditsDATA) t
ON t.media_id = mediaData.id
```

This will work so long as there are no variations among records with the same media_id for the fields needed. If there are variations, you will again see duplicates.

A more reliable option, would be to decide what aggregation criteria makes sense for the media_creditsDATA records. If you don't want more than one record when more than one exists, which do you want? Perhaps there is a way to find the latest, first, etc.? This query could look something like this:

```
Select *
  from mediaData
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (select * 
     from media_creditsDATA
     inner join 
     (select media_id, max(%some_date% or %some_id%
        from media_creditsDATA
       group by media_id) mc_t
     on mc_t.media_id = media_creditsDATA.media_id
    and mc_t.%aggregated_column% = media_creditsDATA.%same_column) t
    ON t.media_id = mediaData.id
```

This would ensure that the subquery will return exactly 1 or 0 rows.

Comment: I don't think there are multiple rows in the media_creditsDATA table with the same media_id. if media_creditsDATA have multiple rows `Distinct` would have removed duplicated rows in the result table.

Comment: Only if the multiple rows, with the same media_id, contains the same non-key data, which wouldn't make much sense from a modelling perspective. The OP's query selects *, so it is likely that non-key data will differ, meaning DiSTINCT will pick both/all.